# Trigger a jQuery keyup event only when an <input> element is not focused

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can use jQuery to bind a function to a keyup event within the context of an `<input>` element such that the event only fires when the `<input>` element is focused:

```
$('#my-input').keyup(function(e) {
  // only fires when the focus is on the <input> element
}
```

**How do I bind a function to a keyup event *outside* the context of the `input` element?**  I want to be able to trigger a keyup event only when the `<input>` element is not focused:

```
$(':not(#my-input)').keyup(function(e) {
  // this code fires regardless of whether the input element is focused
}
```

Unfortunately, the function above is run regardless of whether the `<input>` box is focused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#my-input').focus(function(){
 $('body').unbind('keyup');
}).blur(function(){
 $('body').keyup(function(e) {
  //do stuff
 });
});
```

Comment: This worked, but since I had to respond to keyboard events both in and out of the input box I had to tweak it:

    $('input.lst').eq(0).focus(function(e) {
      $('body').unbind('keypress').keyup(function(e) {
        // keyup in <input>
      });
    }).blur(function(){
      $('body').unbind('keyup').keypress(function(e) {
        // keypress out of <input>
      });
    });

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution is to check if the event target is an input:

```
   $('body').keyup(function(e) {
      if(!$(e.target).is('input')){
         console.log('i am not input');
      }            
   });
```